# How to recover money from old closed/dormant bank accounts in the U.S.?

Tags: united-states, banking, savings

Can anyone answer how to recover cash from (old) closed bank accounts from banks in usa?

Comment: If it's "closed" why is there any money to recover? Could you add a little detail?

Comment: Is your situation a duplicate of "[Closed account, haven't received payment. When has the bank “stolen” my money?](http://money.stackexchange.com/q/62886/26167)"?

Answer (score 4):

If there was still money in the account when it was closed, the bank would have turned over the cash to the state where they operated. Search Google for "unclaimed property <state name>" for the unclaimed property department of the state. The state's website will show if there is money for you.

Comment: Very useful info...